# Status code: 404, 'Not Found' on ASP.NET Core 6.0 Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-6.0

I'm creating a UI by using Windows Forms, and I want the UI can connect to an ASP.NET Core 6.0 Web API.
So I use Postman to test the API's POST function first.

[this is the setting of header in Postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FMUDX.png)
[and this is the setting of Body in Postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yoy0a.png)

And following is the code written by me. When I test my Web API in Postman, it shows:

> 404 Not Found: The requested resource could not be found but may be available again in the future. Subsequent requests by the client are permissible.

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace API0808
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class EmailController : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> SendEmail([FromBody] EmailRequest request)  
        {
            await Task.Delay(100); 
            string email = request.Email;
            return Ok(new { Success = true, Message = "Email received and processed successfully." });  

        }

    }
}
```

I also wrote the EmailRequest.cs to definite EmailRequest

```
namespace API0808
{
    public class EmailRequest
    {
        private string email = "";  
        public string Email { get => email; set => email = value ?? ""; }

    }
}
```

And this is program.cs

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapRazorPages();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

Can anyone help me solve this?

I'm new to Web API, thank you so much.

Comment: *400 Bad Request: The request cannot be fulfilled due to bad syntax.* Can you provide your request body that submit to the API? Thanks.

Comment: The problem was from here: `var json = $"{{\"email\": \"{email}\"}}"; ` This is invalid JSON syntax as extra curly braces. It should be `var json = $"{\"email\": \"{email}\"}"; ` And I would recommend that to use library such as *System.Text.Json* or *Newtonsoft.Json* to serialize the value into JSON string. This simplifies the JSON serialization instead of manually serialize your own which you will highly get the chance in getting the JSON syntax issue.

Comment: Thanks for your response! I have updated the request body that submit to the API.

Comment: I will try to learn the using of library, thank you for your advice!
But now I have new trouble, for connecting my API to Postman.
Cuz I found that there seems to be something wrong in my API code ><
I would really appreciate it if you could help me fixing it ><

Comment: 404 Not found means your API endpoint is not found. Does your API is hosting/debugging while you send the request? I believe that by default .NET Core Web API is configured with Swagger in the pipeline (refer to Program.cs). You may also check the Swagger (by hosting/debugging the API) to see whether that API endpoint route is correct.

Comment: I suggest you could also post your program.cs to let us see if you have specific route for your application.

Comment: Thanks for the assistance!! I have updated the code of program.cs.
But it seems like there is no swagger in the pipeline of ASP.Net Core 6

Comment: When creating the project, there's no choice like "enable OpenAPI support in ASP Net.Core" (I have updated some images to illustrate this part)

Comment: Do not ever change the entire body of your question to be a new question.

Comment: Ok, I'm sorry for causing the inconvenience><, I will pay attention to it next time I post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One such scenario where user will get `404 Not Found:` is `app.MapControllers();` is not present or commented out in `Program.cs`.

[image]
[image]

**Be informed**, based on the code provided, it is working as expected.
The only change I did was changed the content type to `Content-Type:application/json`

[image]

**EDIT#**
**I still do not find any issue with your code.** Hope your port number is correct.

The following lines of code (for Swagger) added to make it run on local environment.

```
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();
...
```

```
// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}
```

**Controller code:**

```
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class EmailController : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> SendEmail([FromBody] EmailRequest request)
        {
            await Task.Delay(100);
            string email = request.Email;
            return Ok(new { Success = true, Message = "Email received and processed successfully." });

        }
        public class EmailRequest
        {
            private string email = "";
            public string Email { get => email; set => email = value ?? ""; }

        }
    }
```

**Folder Structure**

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply!
I changed the content type to 'Content-Type:application/json' like you did, but it's still can't work ><

Comment: And the code: 'app.MapControllers();' wasn't appear indeed, I also add it into my program.cs! (But Postman still appear 404 not found error...)

Comment: Share your program.cs  (and startup.cs if you have).

Comment: var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapRazorPages();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();

Comment: I've post my program.cs in my post, too. Thank you!!

Comment: Edited the answer. Hope that helps